# Hamburger button collapsing multiple divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following button:

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed burger-button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1,#bs-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
```

And the following two divs:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse list-links" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1" style=" margin-left: 25%;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse list-links ftr" id="bs-navbar-collapse-2"
         style="width: 870px; margin: auto;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav  ">
            <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sixth</a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>
```

In the mobile version of the page, they both must not be seen and must be only reached through the hamburger button on top of the page. The problem is that both of the divs are hidden, but only the first one is seen, when the burger button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me. I tested it on Bootply in Firefox. 
Please have a look: [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/ZnZbf7hk9h)

I used Bootstrap (v3.3.7) and JQuery (v3.1.1)

Have you added the JQuery dependency to your project?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple div tags, you can use multiple ul tags like that

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sixth</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

See  [that example in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h).

If you have to do that with multiple toggle-targets; it looks like in order to toggle-target to work, the target should be children of some nav element. So, if the second div is in the footer you may try to wrap it with a nav tag like this:

```
<footer>
    <nav>
        <div id="bs-navbar-collapse-2" ...>
          ...
        </div>
    </nav>
<footer>
```

Note that this may cause need for some other css work to prevent unwanted styling.

Comment: The thing is that bot uls are in different places of the page (top and bottom).